# Google Maps API v3 add another button next to undo button when drawing a Polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons, google-polyline

I'm working with Google Maps API v3. When you edit a polygon, an "undo" button appears next to updated vertice.

I'm absolutely sure I've seen some times ago someone posting a jsfiddle where he demonstrates how to add another button next to this undo button, but I can't find it whereas I'm seeking for this link for 1 hour. It wasn't on [geocodezip](http://geocodezip.com)'s website but I can't find its topic.

Can someone show me where I can find this implementation ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the link](http://jsbin.com/ajimur/10) you're seeking for. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831382/google-maps-v3-delete-vertex-on-polygon).

Comment: Really strange, with my Firefox theme it didn't work, and when I disable the theme, it perfectly works... But thanks for the link !