# delete node from a user created google maps polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I need to allow users to create polylines on a google map and also allow them to delete a node between the polylines they created. The result of this removal should be a new polyline connecting the two new neighboring nodes. At the moment I'm struggling with allowing a user to delete a node. I've researched a bit and found [a google reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/delete-vertex-menu) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831382/google-maps-v3-delete-vertex-on-polygon). Unfortunately, both of them assume that I have a reference to the polyline somewhere, which I don't, since the polyline is being created dynamically by the user.

This is the code that I currently use :

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 45.797436, lng: 24.152044 },
        zoom: 12
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
            ]
        },
        markerOptions: {
            icon: '/Mvc/Content/Styles/dropDownArrow.png'
        },
        polylineOptions: {
            editable: true,
        }
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', markerCompleted);
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', polylineCompleted);

    function markerCompleted(marker) {
        var coordinates = { lng: marker.getPosition().lng(), lat: marker.getPosition().lat() };
        alert('The coordinates for the new marker are: lat:' + coordinates.lat + ', long: ' + coordinates.lng);
    }

    function polylineCompleted(polyline) {

    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

What I've tried is to map the `polyline` parameter inside the `polylineCompleted` event handler to a global variable, and then use the solution found in the SO link to somehow update the polyline, after which, using the `getMap()` and `setMap()` functions of the `DrawingManager` class, to update the map, but I got stuck. Is there any way of allowing a user to delete a polyline node, without having a reference to the polyline object?

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do and what doesn't work. One question though: do you really need to use the drawingManager?

Comment: How does the user dynamically add a polyline?  How do they delete a node.  [The code posted just creates a blank map](http://jsfiddle.net/v281prg5/)

Comment: Are you expecting to delete a node and get 2 separate polylines?

Comment: @MrUpsidown this is an example I found in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools, I've just adapted it to suit my needs. If there's another easier way, please tell me.

Comment: @geocodezip yes, it does; the users would add their own markers and polylines. I want to allow the users to delete the nodes between the polylines they created.

Comment: @not_a_bot No, instead I want the two new neighboring nodes to connect themselves with a new polyline.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in the question, I have edited the text to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is what you are trying to achieve, but here is an example on how to let a user add and remove nodes from a polyline without using the drawingManager.

```
var map, polyline, markers = new Array();

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.291, 153.027),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {

        addPoint(event.latLng);
    });
}

function removePoint(marker) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        if (markers[i] === marker) {

            markers[i].setMap(null);
            markers.splice(i, 1);

            polyline.getPath().removeAt(i);
        }
    }
}

function addPoint(latlng) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });

    markers.push(marker);

    polyline.getPath().setAt(markers.length - 1, latlng);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {

        removePoint(marker);
    });
}

initialize();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/c7yfkcke/)</kbd>

Click on the map to add a point and click on a marker to remove a point.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for.